# Â character when inserting £ symbol into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table using PHP and when i use the `£` symbol, it inserts a `Â` instead.

for example, if i input *£35* into the table via PHP, its inserting `Â£35` instead.

How can i stop the `Â` from inserting in front of the `£` symbol?

my sql query in PHP is as simple as:

```
$sql="INSERT into table (value1, value2) values ('£35', 'value2') ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Verify you are using the right encoding

Comment: do you mean the right encoding in the database?

Comment: Here's what's wrong with your question - first, you never said what you use to look data up in MySQL - is it PHP script, a GUI such as SQLYog nor did you mention any encodings or character sets used upon connecting to the database and you didn't mention what's the table's character set. On top of everything you use deprecated mysql_* functions. Bottom line is that what you asked here is the same as if  I went to a car mechanic and said "My car isn't running." without taking the car there and expecting an answer that'll fix it.

Comment: Your SQL query explicitly inserts 'Â£35'. Why would you expect something else to be inserted?

Comment: @Wooble i didnt mean to put the Â£35' in the query, see my edit

Comment: FWIW, I'd avoid using currency signs altogether. Just store the decimal value in a DECIMAL data type and, if you must store the currency type, store that as the ISO code for that currency in a separate column (GBP, USD, CAD). It's just liable to cause confusion otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an encoding problem, make your life easier with using [UTF-8 for PHP and MySQL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).

Call `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db);` before you do any queries or updates, this will tell the database to deliver UTF-8, independend of the database configurations. Of course it would be better to use MySqli or PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: its still doing it, i have added mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn); before the insert query

Comment: @user2710234 - And did you store your PHP file in the UTF-8 encoding? Have a look at the linked article.

Comment: @user2710234 - Hmm, could you please check your page with this [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/)? The HTML page should be stored UTF-8 encoded and the header should be correctly set, like `<meta charset="UTF-8">` for HTML5. Of course the charset should be set before inserting _and_ before reading. Enter new data to the database, existing data could be stored invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to escape the string?

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string("£35");
```

Then obviously insert `$value` in your database. Please note that this function will try to connect to the database, using the last link opened by `mysql_connect()`.

As Shivan said, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and you should use `mysqli_*` when possible.